# How do I implement a custom error notification system in Python?

Tags: python, exception

Hello, dear Community.

I need to implement a custom error class in Python, which needs to be notified to the user in a special way. I have thought of something like this:

```
class CustomError(Exception)

    def __init__(self, component, err_type, message):

        super(CustomError, self).__init__(message)
        component.custom_error_notification(err_type, message)


class MyComponent:

    def run_some_code(self):

        try:

            # Some code
            raise CustomError(self, err_type, message)

        except CustomError:

            pass

    def custom_error_notification(self, err_type, message):

        # Display the error though a custom "channel".
        # This needs to remain inside MyComponent class.
```

I have two questions about this.

1. Is it a *good practice* to let the Exception class display
   the error message on its own via my custom notification system,
   or should I rather do that manually in the `except` clause?
2. What would be the most appropriate way of avoiding to pass
   'self' among the arguments every time I rise a `CustomError`? How
   could the error infer the environment in which it has been raised,
   so to properly call the custom_error_notification method of the
   object that has caused the error?

(I am interested in Python 3, however, I will need to port this script to IronPython, eventually...)

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You might get better answers over at code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's not clear why you are raising `CustomError` at all, rather than immediately calling `customer_error_notification`. Raise the exception if something farther up the call stack will catch it and call your notification function.

Comment: An exception is a *value*; its initialization shouldn't have side effects like doing I/O. Save the component and the error type in the exception, and let whoever *catches* the exception call the saved components `customer_error_notification` method.

Comment: @chepner Thank you very much, I am really such a noob at programming. Exceptions, shouldn't have side effects, noted down. I will just call the `customer_error_notification` in the except clause of the catcher.